# Getting Glyph names using Core Text

Tags: macos, core-text

For a small side project, I need to have all glyph names available in a font. So, I thought to make this:

```
CTFontRef f = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Zapfino"), 40, NULL);

CFIndex count = CTFontGetGlyphCount(f);
printf("There are %ld glyphs\n", count);

for (CGGlyph i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
{
    CTGlyphInfoRef gi = CTGlyphInfoCreateWithGlyph(i, f, CFSTR("(c)"));
    CFStringRef name = CTGlyphInfoGetGlyphName(gi);
    CGFontIndex idx = CTGlyphInfoGetCharacterIdentifier(gi);

    printf("Glyph: %4hu, idx: %4hu ", i, idx);
    CFShow(name);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Creating the font and getting the glyph count works just fine. The name of the glyph is always NULL though. The CTGlyphInfoRef variable 'gi' gets a value. Any thoughts? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `CTGlyphInfo` is about. It's not a way to query for information about a glyph. It's a representation of a substitution of a glyph for a string. You can set a glyph info object as the value for the `kCTGlyphInfoAttributeName` attribute in an attributed string. That glyph then replaces that range of attributed text, if the text matches the base string.

You can use `CGFontCopyGlyphNameForGlyph()` to get the name for a glyph from a font. You can create the `CGFontRef` directly using the `CGFontCreate...()` functions. You can also create one from a `CTFont` using `CTFontCopyGraphicsFont()`.

Comment: Figured so much... It's a weird thing to have to use several API's with different levels of abstraction to get at these things... CTFont and CGFont are functionally almost but not quite identical.